# C++ two dependent objects?

Tags: c++

```cpp
class D {
 public:
  void HelloWorld(){cout << "Hello" << endl;}
};

class B {
    public:
    void SetCallBack(std::function<void()> callback) {
        callback_ = callback;
    }

    private:
    std::function<void()> callback_;
};

class A {
    public:
    A(B *b) : b_(b) {}
     
    std::function<void()> Helper(){
      return [](){d_->HelloWorld(); };
    }
  
    private:
    B *b_; 
    std::unique_ptr<D> d_;  
};

class C {
    public:
    C(std::unique_ptr<B> b, std::unique_ptr<A> a) 
    : b_(std::move(b)), 
      a_(std::move(a)) {
        b_->SetCallBack(a_->Helper());
    }
  
    private: 
    std::unique_ptr<B> b_;
    std::unique_ptr<A> a_;
};
```

Questions:

1. When B holds a copy of A's member function, does it mean B also holds a pointer to A?
2. Given A's constructor depends on B, B has to be declared first in C and destructed later.  But is this a buggy code that A also depends on B and when A is destructed if B calls the callback, what happens?

Comment: you need a prototype `class B;` before *class A*. The rest looks ok not mentioning missing `;`.

Comment: What you wrote doesn't even compile, even if you were to fix the typos like the uppercase `C` in `class` and the missing semicolons. `Helper()` returns `void`, you can't simply assign the result of calling `Helper()` to a `std::function`. Even if this were rewritten correctly, member functions are not the same as normal function. A member function for `void (Foo::*)()` can't be bound to `std::function<void()>`, it must satisfy an `INVOKE` expression which means it can only bind to `std::function<void(Foo&)>` or `std::function<void(Foo*)>`

Comment: Please make the code compilable unless you have a question about compilation errors. If you do, include those errors.

Comment: @Human-Compiler thanks! It should compile now.

Comment: Doing `a->Helper()` after `std::move(a)` is trouble!

Comment: This is still not a [mre].  Of note, nothing can be done with A's member variables where you have `/* do something with A's member variables*/`.  Try it.  It won't compile because you haven't captured a pointer to any `A`..